# Swift UITextfield Delegate Function "shouldChangeCharactersIn" - How can I stop editing for a second UITextfield?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem, I have two Textfields and want a max length of 20 Characters for both.

I use the following code but it only works for my first Textfield. What did I wrong? I hope someone can help me.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        if textField === nameTextField {
            
            let currentText = nameTextField.text
            guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText!) else {
                return false
            }
            
            let updateText = currentText?.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)
            return updateText?.count ?? 0 < 20
            
        } else if textField === numberTextField {
            let currentText = numberTextField.text
            guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText!) else {
                return false
            }
            
            let updateText = currentText?.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)
            return updateText?.count ?? 0 < 20
            
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: You probably forgot to set the `delegate` for the second one.

Comment: wow thank you. Really bad from me

Comment: If only these two fields have the delegate set, then you don't need the `if` - the code is the same.  Also, you have used a `guard let` for the `Range`, but force unwrapped `currentText` - You should take advantage of the `guard` to conditionally unwrap `textField.text`

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to set the `delegate` for the second one.

Also no need for this complex logic! Just keep the first 20 like:

```
textView.text = String(textView.text.prefix(20))
```

Comment: UItextView text property is an optional